# uniform probability density funcion area( continuous)

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I was watching the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8XLYFzTJzE. In this video the author is explaining a uniform pdf function. In the beginning of the video he explains that for a continuous random variable $X$ the probability of all the possibles values that $X$ could take in the interval $[0,5]$ is the area under the pdf function in the interval $[0,5]$. which should add to $1$. But I can't relate the area with probability.What does he means that all the possible values times the $pdf$ function is the same as calculating the area. I was trying to think of a set with all possible values and if I multiply them by the $pdf$ but it makes no sense to me. I am really confused. Maybe I don't understand the concept of length of an interval and area or I am thinking probably in the wrong way.

Comment: It is not clear if you are trying to find an expected value of a random variable $X$ (related to formulas like $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_X(x)dx$)  or if you are just trying to show that the "sum" of all associated probabilities is 1 (related to formulas like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)dx = 1$).  Can you clarify?  Also, do you know what "integration" is?

Comment: well in a part of the video it says that given all the possible values in the interval times the pdf function was really calcularing the area. I am trying to understand this concept, why multiply a value by all the posibles values on an interval equals the area of the pdf over that interval

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a basic question about integration.  If $f(x)$ is a function then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ is the area under the $f$ curve over the interval $[a,b]$.  For probability, a PDF of a random variable $X$ is a nonnegative function $f_X(x)$ such that, if we want to find the probability that $a \leq X \leq b$ for a particular interval $[a,b]$ of interest, the answer is just $\int_a^b f_X(x)dx$. You can Google "integration" to find out more.

Comment: The picture and description of this link may help understand how integration is the sum of "thin vertical strips," each of which is the multipication of a value $f(x_i)$ with a thickness $\delta$ (and this can be interpreted with language that approaches "multiply by all possible values," which is language that may be helpful for some but unhelpful for others [I would not choose to use that language]). : http://www.vias.org/calculus/04_integration_01_02.html

Comment: Thanks Michael, this helped me understand better the concept